# An error occurs when installing docker on AWS EC2 and creating an instance node

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, keycloak

I installed Docker to install Keycloak on AWS EC2. However, the following error occurs when creating an instance node.

```
$ docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 aws-node1
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(aws-node1) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: error installing docker:
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-97 ~]$
```

The full installation procedure is as follows.

```
$ sudo yum -y install docker 

$ docker –v 
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701 

$ sudo service docker start 

$ sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user 

$ sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0\ 
-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o \ 
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose 

$ docker-compose –v 
docker-compose version 1.25.0-rc2, build 661ac20e 

$ base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 && 
curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker-machine && 
sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine 

$ docker-machine –v 
docker-machine version 0.16.0, build 702c267f 

$ aws configure 
AWS Access Key ID [None]: [My Access Key ID] 
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: [My Secret Access Key]
Default region name [None]: ap-northeast-2 
Default output format [None]: 

$ docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 aws-node1
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(aws-node1) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: error installing docker:
```

I set up "aws configure" by creating an Access Key ID and Secret Access Key for the CLI. However, Docker instance node is not created no matter what.

EC2 was created with "Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) - Kernel 5.10, SSD Volume Type".

Comment: Did you manage to resolve? If yes, how?